# Joomla and Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I just developed for a client an html and css template using Bootstrap latest version (3.X).

The client wants now to include the template in Joomla but this CMS works the 2.3 Bootstrap version so I'm having a lot of trouble cause of class missing etc.

Do you guys know a way to include Bootstrap 3 in Joomla without having conflicts etc ?

Thanks a lot for you answer ;)

Comment: There are a number of people I know who have done this, most likely you will get good help for the Joomla mechanics at the Joomla.stackexchange site [joomla.se].

Comment: I have used other solutions in the past but eventually ended up with the Blank Template. Add bootstrap yourself or use the Bootstrap edition: http://blank.vc/ You can buy an e-book on that site that explains a lot about Joomla templates in general.

Comment: In fact the way that they set things up to avoid conflicts makes it really easy to change js frameworks. However, you will have to make layout overrides to get the right class names for things. So in other words go to the templates ide and use the create override feature for anything you need to fix, then changes the classes. Keep in mind that there are some special Joomla classes that you will need to create, Look in the LESS files for protostar to get a sense of this.